# Check the error code for a shell method which returns value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a sample shell method which:

1. Either returns a value after some processing.
2. Else exit with an exit code if any error occurs.

The sample script is as follows:

**a.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
test(){ # test method
 if [ $1 == 2 ]; then # the condition for checking
  exit 500 # exit with exit code
 else
  echo $1 # do some business logic here and return the value
 fi
}
```

I have problem with checking the error code. To use this *test* method I have another sample script.

**b.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source a.sh
val=`test $1` # call the test method
if [ $? == 500 ]; then # check the value
 echo "here is an error" # error occurs
else
 echo $val # no error, do something with returned value
fi
```

Followings are the output:

**Input:** *./b.sh 10*

**Output:** 10

**Expected output:** 10

**Input:** *./b.sh 2*

**Output:**

**Expected output:** here is an error

I think there is the problem in **b.sh** because `if [ $? == 500 ]; then` is always *false*. Is there any way to make this condition *true* or something to get the error code?

Comment: i think you need to put double square braces, `if [[ $? == 500 ]]; then`

Comment: `500` isn't a valid return code. Return codes are capped at 255. So when you `exit 500` you are actually getting a return code of `244`. Print `$?` to see what I mean.

Comment: Avinash Raj : Its not wotking,

Etan Reisner : Yes, its working

Comment: You should use `return` in procedure instead of `exit`. And use also `return 0` in else case for evidence.

Comment: @EtanReisner Positive integer values are valid values in my case which can be returned by the function. So, if I check for any integer value from b.sh, say 10, it will exit even if there is no error. So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. But you seem not to have understood mine. A return code **cannot** be `500`. Ever. The largest return code you can have is `255`. When you try to exit or return `500` from your function the *actual* return code you get is `244`. Try it and see: `(exit 500); echo $?`

Comment: Definitely it isn't a good idea to name your function `test`, because there is already a command by this name.

Comment: Thanks @ElchononEdelson, Its just an example.. :)

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way of doing this is:

```
if val=$(test "$1"); then
  echo "$val"
else
  echo "An error occurred."
fi
```

The `if` statement tests the status of the command (or pipeline) which follows it, and executes the `then` branch of the status indicated success. The only time you need to explicitly check the value of `$?` is the rare case of a utility which returns different failure status values (and documents what they mean).

Many people seem to think that `[ ... ]` and other such things are part of the syntax of the `if` command. They are not; they are just commands (or builtins) whose names are punctuation. You can use any command whatsoever, or even several in a row; in the latter case, the status checked will be that of the last command.